# Can't compile C++ in gnustep projectcenter

Tags: makefile, gnustep

I've set up gnustep in windows, 
have Gorm and Projectcenter runnng 
and successfully build an Objective-C hello world app
with a UI built by Gorm.

However, adding C++ stuffs like Class etc
will make the project not compile.

The ProjectCenter's "New File" command
doesn't have "cpp", only "c" files.

> Is it that the ProjectCenter doesn't support C++/Obj-C++?
>
> Is there a way to edit the make file to make it compile C++ files?

```
#
# GNUmakefile - Generated by ProjectCenter
#
ifeq ($(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES),)
 GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES := $(shell gnustep-config --variable=GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES 2>/dev/null)
endif
ifeq ($(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES),)
 $(error You need to set GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES before compiling!)
endif

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

#
# Application
#
VERSION = 0.1
PACKAGE_NAME = myapp
APP_NAME = myapp
myapp_APPLICATION_ICON = 


#
# Resource files
#
myapp_RESOURCE_FILES = \
Resources/myapp.gorm \
Resources/Main.gsmarkup \
Resources/MainMenu-GNUstep.gsmarkup \
Resources/MainMenu-OSX.gsmarkup 


#
# Header files
#
myapp_HEADER_FILES = \
AppController.h \
mycls.h

#
# Class files
#
myapp_OBJC_FILES = \
AppController.m

#
# Other sources
#
myapp_C_FILES = \
mycls.c 

myapp_OBJC_FILES += \
myapp_main.m 

#
# Makefiles
#
-include GNUmakefile.preamble
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/aggregate.make
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
-include GNUmakefile.postamble
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (0.6.2), ProjectCenter does not support C++ nor Obj-C++

Support for Obj-C++ is planned for the future though.